# Save JSON into a variable, excluding certain elements of the JSON

Tags: javascript, json, telegram-bot

I'm working on an telegram anti-flood bot, so I created a simple one, save the text and sender ID in a JSON when a message is sent, when another message is sent, check if both are the same and if so, deletes the message; however the method doesn't work sometimes and deletes a different message (eg.: 2 different images without a caption are sent by a user quickly, the second image will be deleted), so I wanted to save all JSON excluding specific elements (like message id and date), because they're always different, so how can i do that?
Here is a JSON message for examples:

```json
{
    message_id: 0,
    from: {
        id: 0,
        is_bot: false,
        first_name: 'John',
        last_name: 'Doe',
        username: 'JohnDoe',
        language_code: 'en-us'
    },
    chat: { id: 0, title: 'Cool Group.', type: 'group' },
    date: 12345,
    text: 'Test Message.'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First store your Object in some variable than delete key-value which you want to exclude.

```js
var x = {
    message_id: 0,
    from: {
        id: 0,
        is_bot: false,
        first_name: 'John',
        last_name: 'Doe',
        username: 'JohnDoe',
        language_code: 'en-us'
    },
    chat: { id: 0, title: 'Cool Group.', type: 'group' },
    date: 12345,
    text: 'Test Message.'
}; 
delete x["message_id"]
delete x["date"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be overkill, but you could make the structure which you expect, with fallback defaults, then merge in the incoming object, ignoring any properties not in the schema or of a different type... call it strict merge.

```js
function strictMerge(a, b) {
  if (!b || typeof b !== typeof a) return a

  if (Array.isArray(a) && Array.isArray(b)) {
    return a.map((item, index) => {
      if (b[index]) {
        return Object.keys(item).reduce((acc, key) => {
          acc[key] = typeof b[index][key] === 'object' && !Array.isArray(b[key]) ?
            this.strictMerge(a[index][key], b[index][key]) : (
              typeof b[index][key] !== 'undefined' ? (
                typeof b[index][key] !== typeof a[index][key] ? a[index][key] : b[index][key]
              ) : a[index][key]
            );
          return acc
        }, {})
      }
      return item
    }, [])
  } else {
    return Object.keys(a).reduce((acc, key) => {
      acc[key] = typeof b[key] === 'object' && !Array.isArray(b[key]) ?
        strictMerge(a[key], b[key]) : (
          typeof b[key] !== 'undefined' ? (
            typeof b[key] !== typeof a[key] ? a[key] : b[key]
          ) : a[key]
        )
      return acc
    }, {})
  }
}


const message = {
  message_id: 0,
  from: {
    id: 0,
    is_bot: false,
    first_name: 'John',
    last_name: 'Doe',
    username: 'JohnDoe',
    language_code: 'en-us'
  },
  chat: {
    id: 0,
    title: 'Cool Group.',
    type: 'group'
  },
  date: 12345,
  text: 'Test Message.',
  foooo: 'barrr'
}


console.log(strictMerge({
  from: {
    id: 0,
    is_bot: false,
    first_name: '',
    last_name: '',
    username: '',
    language_code: ''
  },
  chat: {
    id: 0,
    title: '',
    type: ''
  },
  text: ''
}, message))
```